# Drupal 7 display article from view

Tags: php, drupal-7

Hello I'm beginner with drupal.
I'm displaying my articles (using tag) from views. But I would like to display that with php, not with the configuration panel because i have some modification to do. For example with wordpress :

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().
```

for example I would like to display multiple views on my front page
Is it possible ? 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display multiple views on one page then you just need to create one view with lets say /home path.

and then set the home page path to the path '/home'

After that create multiple views with block display and configure the blocks visibility by configuring the blocks.

Thanks